# How can I calculate a fiscal week

Tags: sql

I would like a column displaying the fiscal week.  Our fiscal year begins in April.

So far I have the below, using     datename(ww,DateAndTime) as Week

```
DateAndTime                 Week 
2015-04-01 22:45             14
2015-06-14 13:22             25
2015-12-02 09:15             49
2016-01-01 07:35              1
```

I would like the output to show:

```
DateAndTime                 Week            Fiscal Week 
2015-04-01 22:45             14                  1
2015-06-14 13:22             25                 12 
2015-12-02 09:15             49                 36              
2016-01-01 07:35              1                 41
```

Comment: So do you want a computed column? A persisted computed column? What are your constraints?

Comment: Tag dbms used, many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.

Comment: Add 52-datename(ww,year-04-01) to the week, modulo 52. You have to use the right year however .For dates before April use the previous year, for dates after April use the current year.

Comment: Is April 1 the beginning of the fiscal year, or is the Sunday of the week that includes April 1 the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand the logic behind the fiscal week (the difference between 1 and 41 is 40, but between 14 and 1 it's 39), maybe I'm missing something or you made a typo.

However, in general you'd do something like this (assuming the difference is 40 weeks):

```
SELECT week, (week+40)%52 AS fw FROM ...
```

If the fiscal year starts at a different week every each (say, 13th or 14th week depending on year), you can use the date and time functions, but they may vary between SQL versions. In MySQL you have `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, `WEEK()`, etc.

For example:

```
SELECT week, (week+(52-WEEK(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(NOW()), '04-01'))))%52 FROM ...
```

But it might be overkill.

Note: It is possible to count the other way: if you subtract the diff from the week instead of adding, you will need to add 52 if the number is negative. You can do that by adding 52 and then doing modulo (%) 52.

Comment: I don't think the week offset is the same constant every year. April 1st 2016 is week 13, in 2019 it is week 14.

Comment: Added a note on how to get around that, but it just feels like overkill to me.